# Jquery Post data is un-defined

Tags: php, jquery, json, wordpress, post

I am trying to send data using jquery post to another page.

in Header.php

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

  $('#My_Button').click(function() {

      var record = { id: 'hello testing' };
      $.ajax({
                url: '../get-a-quote',
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: JSON.stringify(record),
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    //$('#response pre').html( data );
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });


    });
});
</script>
```

It gives me success message, but when i try to recieve data value in footer.php its undefined.

footer.php

```
<script>
<?php
//tried this 
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true); ?>
var dropdown_value = <?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>
alert(dropdown_value);       ////undefined

//tried
// var dropdown_value = <?php echo json_decode($_POST['id']); ?>
// alert(dropdown_value);      //undefined

</script>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK _footer.php_ will be included when the page is rendered and at that time there is no `php://input` available. I would expect to see a page _quote.php_ that is hidden behind the rewrite rule for "../get-a-quote" to handle the AJAX request which would contain the PHP part shown in your above code. Could you please add more details about what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: hi, its a wordpress website i have shifted code to header as well but still its undefined: https://www.mobitsolutions.com/get-a-quote/

Comment: I try to summarize: your `dropdown_value` value should be populated depending on the passed _id_, in your example above `{ id: 'hello testing' }`. In your PHP you would like to check for the passed _id_ and return a list of dropdown values, most likely in JSON, right?

Comment: exectly, i just tried by using cookies its working, but http post is always null if i go with that way.it seems like wordpress is making issues may be.

Comment: I see that you are a really professional expert and SO user so I hope I am not offensive when I say you are quite new to PHP and Wordpress, right? If so I would recommend to read ["AJAX in Plugins"](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) on the official Wordpress page. You need to register your AJAX hook to be called in Wordpress and then call the hook in your JS code to load data from it. Hope that helps.